# Flutter: how to open app using links containing a fragment

Tags: android, flutter, fragment

I'm trying to open a link that contains a fragment like:

https://example.ex.name/#/app

but, unfortunately, it seems that it doesn't care about the fragment, so it opens also links like https://example.ex.name.

I used this [uni_links](https://pub.dev/packages/uni_links) to work with app links. This is my AndroidManifest:

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data
                    android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="*.name"
                    android:fragment="/app"
            />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this package

> https://pub.dev/packages/uni_links

for your deep llinks.